# Is it correct to say "The reason is because ..."?

Tags: grammaticality

In a statement like

> The weeds have grown overnight. *The reason is because* it rained yesterday

Is "*the reason is because*" good grammar? Isn't it better to say

> The weeds have grown overnight *because it* rained yesterday

The second form seems simpler and the words *the reason is* seem to add nothing to the sentence. Is there any technical reason to avoid the longer form?

Comment: I think both forms are correct.

Comment: [much lesser usage compared](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=The+reason+is+because%2C+the+reason+is+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) to "the reason is that" which is my preferred phrase

Comment: The [Oxford dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reason) have a discussion on the phrase *the reason is because* in the usage note for the word *reason*. They conclude that it's acceptable.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"*The reason is because...*" is wrong; the other one is the one to go with.

That "*the reason*" is already explaining why, i.e. the *reason*, so putting also *because* will create a sort of redundancy.

See [this article](http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/072303ReasonBecause.htm), which goes more in depth.

Comment: Great reference, thanks Alenanno. It explains it so much better than I could. I had a feeling there was a kind of *redundancy* in there.

Comment: No problem at all! :)

Comment: There is indeed redundancy. That does not necessarily mean that anything is wrong.

Comment: @Colin I'm not sure I understood you but... Well, usually redundancy, unless you use it intentionally, is not really correct.

Comment: @Alenanno: so the redundancy in using "-s" with "he" is not really correct? And the redundancy of using the negative-polarity "any" with "not" is not really correct? And the redundancy in French of saying "le*s* bon*nes* jeune*s* fille*s*" is not really correct? Languages are full of redundancy. Some instances of it are required by the grammar of a language. Others pass without notice. Some are singled out by prescriptivists as "incorrect" .

Comment: @Colin: I said **usually** for a reason, Colin. My word-choice was not random. In some cases redundancy is correct (_even if in my opinion the examples you provided are different from this case_), but for example, in Italian we usually omit the personal pronoun, unless we want to be specific about it. You talk about prescriptivism, is that a hint meaning that you think "the reason is because" can be correct or acceptable?

Comment: In my view "correct" is a term irrelevant to linguistics, except sociolinguistics. It is a judgment of fashion, like the "correct" fork to use. Is "the reason is because" acceptable? certainly.

Comment: The explanation given in the link is given strictly from the stand point of view and within the limits of grammar. However, the stylistics is not always in strict correspondence to the logic of grammar. At times, redundancy may be viewed as such from the standpoint of grammar, yet it may be making things clearer in a spoken speech and, therefore, absolutely justified. Take for example "a good fiend of George's".This is, in fact, a case of redundancy as the preposition "of" already signals that the fiend belongs to George, so the 's is not needed. Yet, it's absolutely correct to say so.

Comment: I agree with Collin. You may say an expression sounds uneducated, ugly, inelegant, is discouraged by writing manuals, may be redundant, or is dispreferred. But you may not foist your prescriptivist norms on others as objectively “wrong.” Linguistics is a science, not a religion...

Comment: @RichardZ That's a very old answer you've commented on. If I was answering today, I wouldn't write the same answer so I might edit it both to reflect my opinion and to analyse the point of the question in a better way.

Comment: Oh, okay... good job.

Comment: I just want to point out that "the reason is because" is not necessarily a case of redundancy. At first glance, sure, but depending on how the writer/speaker means it, this could actually be less about redundancy - and more about logical chaining or sequencing. In the sense that "the reason is because", could mean something akin to  "the reason is the reason due to the following", in the sense that what proceeds is a dissection of why that was the reason in the first place, and less of a discussion about the reason itself. I know it can be a bit overwhelming. Break the fourth wall.

Answer (score 33):

I am going to disagree with some of the other answers here. I don't think there is anything grammatically wrong with either of the sentences.

> The reason is because it rained yesterday.
> The reason is that it rained yesterday.

I agree that this sentence sounds better with **that,** in part because **because** is redundant. But consider:

> The reason he faked his suicide and went into hiding in Peoria using a fake name is because his life was in danger.
> The reason he faked his suicide and went into hiding in Peoria using a fake name is
> that his life was in danger.

In this case, I think **because** sounds superior to **that**. But don't these sentences have exactly the same grammatical structure? So how can the first one be ungrammatical and other one grammatical? I think the reason **because** sounds better now is that there is a large gap between **reason** and **because,** which means that now the redundancy becomes useful rather than superfluous.

Further, people have been using "the reason is because" for centuries. Consider this quote from Shakespeare (*Romeo and Juliet*):

> thou
> wilt quarrel with a man for cracking nuts, having no
> other reason but because thou hast hazel eyes.

Surely, if *reasons* can't be *because*, this is also ungrammatical.

Finally, let me add that the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/usage-of-reason-is-because-redundant) dictionary agrees. From the conclusion of their long discussion at the above link:

> In sum, "the reason is because" has been attested in literary use for centuries. If you aren't comfortable using the phrase, or feel that it's awkward, don't use it. But maybe lay off the criticism of others—there's really no argument against it. The phrase may grate on your nerves (along with "the reason why is because"), but it puts people who apply it in some very distinguished literary company.

Comment: "The event happened BECAUSE xxx", but "The reason that the event happened WAS xxx"

Comment: Upvoting **because the reason** we have redundancy in language is to improve its reliability as a means of communication.

Comment: I agree with you Peter, I too think your 'because' version sounds more natural. But the two sentence don't have quite the same structure. The problem is that the verb 'be' is a copular or linking verb, and theoretically you're not meant to use an adverbial clause (because...) after a copular verb. But a 'that' clause is OK because it's technically a noun clause. But then we're not meant to say 'It's me' either, but we all do. That's why I say theoretically. I'm with Colin Fine and Fumblefingers.

Comment: @RandomIdeaEnglish: I agree. We do not say "the reason is because." *Because* starts ADV clauses. *That* starts NOUN clauses. Alenanno is also correct. "The reason is because" is redundant. (The same principle applies to "the reason why." We don't need the word *why*. It is redundant.)

Comment: I agree the first of your 2nd pair is better, but I think your **reason** isn't exactly the right one. It's **because** that phrasing invites us split off the introductory *"The only good reason to..."*, leaving the advisory maxim *"Go to graduate school in English [is] because you love it (not for other reasons)"*. Which I can't actually parse anyway - did you mean *"in England"*?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: would it have been clearer if I'd said *in Mathematics*?

Comment: Not really! Perhaps in US usage *"graduate school in [subject]"* is more clearly recognised as a "self-contained" composite noun phrase. In the UK we don't normally use "graduate school" as a noun anyway, and I'm certainly not familiar with the idea distinguishing between different types thereof that specialise in a particular subject. Also, I assume in your example you mean *because you love English*, but my attempt to parse it ends up with *because you love that graduate school (which specialises in English)*.

Comment: The examples above sound fine, but compare them with the following: *The only good reason to go to grad school is that you love English. The only good reason to go to grad school is because you love English....The reason is because you love English*

Comment: I don't think the problem is redundancy but rather a violation of the syntax of _because,_ which is always _A because B,_ where A and B are complete statements.  But ‘The reason is’ is not a complete statement, unless _is_ is read existentially.

Answer (score 6):

I think "The reason is *that* it rained yesterday" would be more appropriate. "The reason is because" does not seem to make much logical sense.

Comment: This echoes my feelings about *the reason is because*. I tend to overuse the word *that*, but in some cases it seems *right*

Answer (score 3):

In ‘The Penguin Guide to Plain English’, Harry Blamires describes ‘the reason is because’ as ‘causational overkill’. You can see what he means, but my impression is that in BrEng, at least, ‘the reason is because’ is used at least as much as ‘the reason is that’.

Comment: I see [no evidence in NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reason+is+because%2Creason+is+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) that Brits are any more likely than Americans to use *reason is because* rather than *reason is that*. Big difference from my point of view is we're more likely to say the usage is *gormless*, where Americans might call it something like *dorky*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It's always worth remembering that nGrams records written, not spoken, language. I mentioned BrEng, only because I don't hear much AmEng.

Comment: Oh absolutely. I certainly wouldn't significantly disparage anyone for *saying* things like this - I set the bar a **lot** lower for speech. But that doesn't imply people who don't already *know* "correct" usage should learn to "talk improper". I think many people trying to learn "normal" usage here on ELU are misled by answers/comments endorsing usages which really shouldn't be encouraged. And that's notwithstanding the fact that, like you, I don't really do "correct" in general. Sloppy language isn't exactly a cardinal sin, but it shouldn't be overly encouraged - especially on ELU.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: 'Setting the bar lower' for speech makes it sound as if spoken langauge is in some way inferior to written language, but that's perhaps not what you meant. I hear many people whose speech is above reproach say 'the reason is . . .because', to the extent that it is now 'normal usage'. The problem with a site like ELU is in knowing who it's for. I don't regard it as being primarily for foreign learers of English, although I'm happy to help them where I can.

Comment: Yes, I'd *like* to think ELU is primarily for "competent speakers" to explore the intricacies of (spoken & written) usage. But undeniably (esp of late) there are many "beginners" whose main exposure is to speech and "social network" postings. I don't think speech is "inferior" in any meaningful sense - I just mean many people have a tendency to ignore/downplay "correct" usage in such contexts. I often write things in Comments (hopefully not Answers) here on ELU that I myself would decry (or at least, not defend) in less "ephemeral" written contexts.

Comment: Say hello to my little friend :  **the reason is because**

Answer (score 2):

"The reason is because" *means the same thing as* "The reason is [that]", but it does NOT follow that *because* is redundant or incorrect.  Instead, *because* is playing a non-semantic role in the larger sentence.

This is easiest to understand in the context of spoken language, where the *because* would be acting as a [filler word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_%28linguistics%29).  Imagine stretching it out further: "The reason is, um, because, well, like, ..."  It's perfectly normal in English to use semantically duplicative words as filler, instead of *um*/*er*/*uh*.

In written language, *because* is instead used (or not used) to improve rhythm and flow.  Consider the following two examples, both from writers whose stylistic chops are impeccable:

> “If the fellow who wrote it seems to know more of my goings and comings than he could without complicity of mine, **the reason is because** he is a lovely old boy and quite took possession of me while I was in Boston”
>   [1915, Robert Frost]
>
> “… one of **the reasons** why I am not particularly well read today **is because** I have spent so large a part of the last twenty years rereading Dickens and Jane Austen.”
>   [1932, Alexander Woollcott]

(both quotations copied from [this article](https://motivatedgrammar.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/the-reason-is-because/) which contains a good deal more descriptive analysis of this construction)

In both cases, omitting the *because* (or substituting *that*) would make the clause transition jar.  In the latter case, with the caused-state in between *the reason* and *is because*, the *because* also serves to remind the reader of the overall structure of the sentence.

Comment: *[...] both from writers whose stylistic chops are impeccable* Argument from authority...

Answer (score 0):

1. The reason is because... "X".
2. The reason is that... "X".

The phrase "the reason is" implies a causal relationship between two events or states.  For example the reason that the wagon is red is that I painted it with red paint.  The wagon being red is caused by my painting it.  I could also say the wagon is red because I painted it.  Cause: I painted; effect:  it is red.

So If I say, “the reason is because,” what I really am saying is that the cause of there being a reason is that I painted it.  This is akin to saying, “I painted the wagon and that is why it is red because I painted it.”

So, indeed No. 1 is a redundancy, a grammatical error, and a logical violation.  Much like saying “ATM machine” – (a machine that makes ATMs I suppose), or that something “is comprised of” its constituent parts.  But I suppose those are separate topics.

Answer (score 0):

> The weeds have grown overnight. The reason is because it rained yesterday.

That's the kind of sentence a teacher of expository writing is likely to flag as *verbose*  or *chatty/talky*, not as "ungrammatical" or "incorrect".

**because** is being used as a stand-in for  **that**:

> The reason is that it rained yesterday.

But **because** and the content clause can be tacked directly onto the preceding clause without "the reason is" between them, yielding more succinct expression, which is considered a virtue in expository writing.

> The weeds have grown overnight because it rained yesterday.

A teacher of fiction writing might welcome the original version as being true to how many people speak.

Answer (score -2):

If you say "The reason...is because" you are redundant. "The reason" is another way to say "because." 
Also, I think it is incorrect to say "The reason why." This is because the question word "why" entices you to answer with "because," and it is grammatically incorrect to say "the reason...is because."

Answer (score -2):

If viewed in isolation, it is not a very smooth English phrase, though it is right grammatically. But this could be an answer to a very specific query, where the question was stressed on the word “reason”.