# Is "is that" grammatically correct?

Tags: verbs

Can the words "*is*" and "*that*" be used back-to-back in the following sentence?

> The reason I went to the store is that I ran out of milk.

Similarly, can "*is*" and "*because*" be used as such? For example:

> The reason I went to the store is because I ran out of milk.

Comment: You're asking about the construction `X Be` _that_ `S`. A _that_ complement clause (as here) can be used as the predicate of an identificational sentence with `X` (here `X` = _The reason (that/why) I went to the store_) and the form of `Be` is _is_. A _because_ clause is also acceptable when the `X` is a reason or cause; this is the case here, but not everywhere.

Comment: Why do you think these wouldn't be grammatical?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it correct to say "The reason is because ..."?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34396/is-it-correct-to-say-the-reason-is-because)

Answer (score 0):

Anywho, to answer your question, Bob, I believe it is, it would be much simpler to rephrase/reconstruct your sentence and instead say, "I went to the store because I ran out of milk." This flows much more easily.

I agree with what the comment above me says as well. You may say "is that", although I HATE the word "that", but you may not say "is because" because they are both the same type of word.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, Berry.  This comes across as a bit of a comment instead of an answer.  Please take a moment to [tour] the site and read the [FAQ].  Stick around and you'll be able to contribute comments soon.

Answer (score -1):

According to http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/072303reasonbecause.htm "is that" is fine, but "is because" is not correct because of redundancy.

~~Droonkid

Comment: Oh, that's BS. _Because_ is fine, but _that_ is shorter.

Comment: I'd avoid it, but redundancy is ranked on a scale of acceptability.  Some redundancies are seen as fine and dandy. For this one, see [M-W's usage note](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/usage-of-reason-is-because-redundant).