# Is the word "that" required in a "[aspect] is that [consequence]" structure?

Tags: american-english

Writing a scientific report and got stuck on the following. I have a few sentences like this:

> The downside of cycling through the rain is I will be cold

Which is basically: "The [some aspect] is [consequence]".

A colleague mentioned it is incorrect without the word "that" (this might be because of our native language, which is Dutch):

> The downside of cycling through the rain is **that** I will be cold

So, what is the role of "that" here? Is it required?

*Comparable questions that I think do not cover this exactly:* [Is 'that' required in this sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/428593/is-that-required-in-this-sentence), [Is "is that" grammatically correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200139/is-is-that-grammatically-correct)

Comment: In formal writing, such as a scientific report, it is probably better to put *that* in. In everyday English, you don't need to.

Comment: Like is only required in certain phrases. Such as, for instance, *I like **that** it is cold* or ***that*** *is what I'm talking about*. But in the case of the sentence in the question, it's not required to added after a *to be* verb.